# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in HTML

Tags: jquery, regex

I am getting the syntax error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

From this jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("head").append("<meta name="twitter:image" content="https:\/\/example\.org\/thumb.php?src=sample.jpg&t=a&w=200&h=200" />");
    });
</script>
```

What kinds of mistakes produce this Javascript Syntax error?

Comment: use single quotes around the html content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ones in which you use the wrong kind of quote:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("head").append("<meta name='twitter:image' content='https:\/\/example\.org\/thumb.php?src=sample.jpg&t=a&w=200&h=200' />");
    });
</script>
```

Use an editor with syntax highlighting: it'll make spotting such mistakes a breeze next time.

Comment: (To be clear, the problem was you were effectively quoting the `)` at the end of your call, so the interpreter crapped out. Maybe read up on the rules about " and ' ?)

Comment: of course, I already use sublime text but it wasn't that evident the syntax highlighting, thanks

Comment: Interesting, because that's exactly how I found your problem: I pasted it into sublime text and noticed it was the wrong colour. Everything inside your append call should have been string-literal-colour, but instead some of it was being highlighted like html: made me realise that something had ended the string literal too soon :)